# How to call redis-cli get using Bash?

Tags: bash, redis, redis-cli

Is it possible to call `redis-cli` in bash?

I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    echo "Text read from file: $line"
        echo 'keys $line' | redis-cli | sed 's/^/get /' | redis-cli
done < "$1"
```

It returns:

```
line 4: redis-cli: command not found
```

I am trying to match the redis key `nt:<numbers>` as key from input file and display.

Sample input:

```
nt:60136667431
```

The command I run:

```
./updateT.sh input.txt
```

Is there any way I can call `redis-cli get cmd` in script for many key values passed as input?

Comment: If you don't have it installed then of course you can't.

Comment: Looking at some examples, I don't think that's how you use it, though. Probably investigate `xargs` and also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash

Comment: @tripleee i have it installed. redis-cli works in command line but not in bash

Comment: Bash *is* the command line. At the "command line" where you can run it succesfully, if you type `type -a redis-cli` what do you get? What does your `PATH` look like?

Comment: Also, your code doesn't look correct, but we have no idea what you want it to actually do. Could you please [edit] the question to show what you hope those commands would do?

Comment: @tripleee yes i get it... i am reading input from a txt file hence m writing the script in a .sh file

Comment: That doesn't really clarify anything; can you please [edit] your question if you can think of a way to add something actually useful to show us where exactly you are stuck?

Answer (score 2):

Installation problems aside, I am guessing you want something like

```
while read -r line; do
    redis-cli keys "$line" |
    xargs -n 1 echo redis-cli get
done <"$1"
```

Take out the `echo` if it prints things which look correct to you. If you can `get` multiple keys, maybe take out the `-n 1`.

Given the input line `nt:60136667431` this will perform

```
redis-cli keys nt:60136667431
```

and pass each output line from that to `redis-cli get`. So if it prints `foo` and `bar` we will end up with

```
echo redis-cli get foo
echo redis-cli get bar
```

... where again obviously take out the `echo` if those are the commands you would like to end up executing.  If you take out `-n 1` it will collect as many as it can into

```
echo redis-cli get foo bar
```

though if you have on the order of thousands of results it might still need to split the command line up into multiple commands because of argument list length constraints in the underlying OS. (Google `ARG_MAX`.) I have no idea whether `redis-cli` supports this syntax; brief googling suggests not.

Comment: I left out the complex `[[ -n "$line" ]]` stuff for simplicity. If you really have files with an incomplete last line, maybe fix them instead.

Comment: still got error when i tried this code
./updateTime.sh: line 3: redis-cli: command not found
redis-cli get

Comment: Yeah, you need to solve the installation problem first.